# Automatically open pdf files in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of my clients wants to have on his website the links to pdf files opened automatically in a new window.

I’ve written this code and it works :

```
$("a[target!='_blank'][href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");
```

I was wondering if there was other good solutions ?

Comment: That's pretty much what I've used in the past. I don't see any issues with it if you're unable to amend the HTML directly.

Comment: code seems correct somehow

Comment: Why have you got `[target!='_blank']` in your selector?

Comment: What type of good solution you want now???

Comment: Do you mean new window, because you've actually written new tab

Comment: @putvande I check if there is target="_blank" before.

Comment: @jumpingcode doesn't matter, just want to open in a new window or a new tab (depends on user's preferences).

Comment: @Manwal nothing! its just getTogether party....;) cheers^^

Comment: @SébastienGicquel But the way the title is worded may attract answers of new window only.

Comment: @Manwal Just curious to know if there are other solutions.

Comment: @jumpingcode Ok, i understand, what do you suggest ?

Comment: There's no correct answer to this question, you're asking for suggestions as to other solutions when you have one already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the .pdf in a new tab of the web browser,

```
$("a[target!='_blank'][href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");
```

To open the .pdf with the default program,

```
$("a[target!='_system'][href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_system");
```

Answer (score 0):

Target="_system" opens the link in a preferred program on a mobile device.